# Why is my fire simulation so light?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, smoke-simulation, fire

I have been struggling to get a match tip to actually look like it's on fire and no matter what material shaders I try, I can't seem to achieve what everyone else does, I can in other scenes, just not this one. :(
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try black environment ...

[image]

Also there is nothing wrong to use Principle BSDF node :)

[image]
[image]

blender 2.8.1
[image]

blender 2.8.3 - 9.x (Mantaflow solver)
[image]